# Tensorflow model.fit crashed in while loop

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to optimise the learning_rate parameter of my ML-model with a while-loop.
The first model completes all of its learning steps, however, the in the second iteration of the while-loop and thus the second call of model.fit() fails already in the first epoch. No output is generated.

Edit: 
I have traced the problem to the Tensorboard callback. Without that call-back the loop successfully trains all 4 models, while with the callback the loop fails at the beginning of the second iteration/model fit. What am I doing wrong here?

```
for lr in [0.005, 0.001, 0.0005, ...]:
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    ...
    ## create model
    model = createModel(...)
    model.compile(learning_rate = lr)
    
    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(...)
    model.fit(..., callbacks = [tensorboard_callback])
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong or why this does not work? 
Thank you very much!

Environment:
I am working on a Debian server with two Nvidia Tesla V100S (32GB) cards (only one is used for training the model), 128 CPU cores and 2TB main memory
Python: 3.7.9
Tensorflow: 2.4.1
The implementation is inside a Jupyter notebook

Comment: Can you add more details about what callback that you used ?

Comment: Sure. The TensorBoard callback only specifies the logDirectory. During each iteration in the for-loop that directory is changed. Just before the 2nd model.fit fails, the log is generated and is available in the TensorBoard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. There was an incorrect version of cuDNN installed. Thanks